# What kind of server should I build to run Selenium and Appium automation tests?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, server, webdriver, appium

I am building a server to run my Selenium/Appium automation scripts. I was told that I would need a more sophisticated server, like machine learning, because Webdrivers require more processing. Just wondering what everyone uses and if it works

Best

Comment: Using a server with multiple processing power like 4-8 cores or GPU will help for parallel testing. Also a sufficient amount of RAM is needed. At least 4-8 gigs.

Answer (score 0):

Using a server with multiple processing power like 4-8 cores or GPU will help for parallel testing. Also a sufficient amount of RAM is needed. At least 4-8 gigs.